# How to create a QueueWorker and run it without cron

Tags: 9, queue

Can someone please help me with an example on how to create a `QueueWorker` class, add items, and run it inside `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` or anywhere in a module file?

Basically, what I want is adding an item to the queue and run it soon after a node save, without waiting until the next cron runs.

Comment: The hook you want is probably `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`, which runs after successful node save.  `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` is run before save and will be run even if the save fails.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Main thing I'm after is a good example on how to run the queueworker from the hook. I created the QueueWorker and added an item, but, I'm not sure how to programmatically run it from  `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`

Comment: You should be able to extract what you need from [`Cron::processQueues()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/function/Cron%3A%3AprocessQueues/9)

Comment: Let's ask: Why you need to queue it when you want it to run immediately?

Comment: Thanks @Clive it was helpful. Fair question @leymannx. I have some business logic inside `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` which require me to save a node from one content type when updating another content type node. When I try to save the other node inside the `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` with `$other_entity->save()` it simply doesn't save it. That's when I thought maybe queueing it and claiming the queue would be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is a different kind of queue worker. See https://mglaman.dev/blog/flush-and-run-using-kernelterminate-improve-page-speed-performance

A simple example:

*/src/EventSubscriber/TaskOnTerminateSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\TerminateEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

/**
 * A subscriber running a task by request
 */
class TaskOnTerminateSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * TRUE if a task run is requested.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $runTask = FALSE;

  /**
   * Request a task run
   */
  public function runTask() {
    $this->runTask = TRUE;
  }

  /**
   * Run task if requested.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\TerminateEvent $event
   *   The Event to process.
   */
  public function onTerminate(TerminateEvent $event) {
    if ($this->runTask) {
      // replace this with your long-running task
      sleep(10);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [KernelEvents::TERMINATE => [['onTerminate', 150]]];
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.task_on_terminate_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\TaskOnTerminateSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Trigger the task in hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/insert/update:

```
\Drupal::service('mymodule.task_on_terminate_subscriber')->runTask();
```

runTask() could contain arguments, like the entity ID. You can also make the service store multiple tasks in an array class property, which would then be a queue stored in memory processed right after the response is flushed to the client.